# Circular waveguide modes visual difference

Tags: electromagnetism, waveguide

As we can see bellow TE01 and TE11 mode taken from the manual bellow.
The fiirence between the two in the first index,but the shape is totally changed.
Is there a logic regarding the shape of the mode with respect to the indexes?

https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Applications_of_Maxwells_Equations_(Cochran_and_Heinrich)/12%3A_Waveguides/12.05%3A_Circular_Waveguides

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the reference you gave Equations 12.5.13 and 12.5.14 define the $TE_{mn}$ mode components. The index $m$ defines a series of modes having the same axial (angular) *m-fold* symmetry. The second index refers to the radial distribution of the field and is numbered by the roots of the $m^{th}$ Bessel function $J_m'(k_nR) = 0$ where $J_m'(x)=\frac{dJ_m(x)}{dx}$ and $R$ is the radius of the waveguide. This ensures the boundary condition on the inner metal surface $H_r(r=R)=0$.

Comment: Hello hyportnex so m is angular and n is radial. so for 01 there is no angular and radial is 1?
i cant see it in the photo.
also for TE 11 we have 1 angular and one radial,i cant see this data in  the TE11 photo.
could you please explain that?
Thanks.

Comment: hint: the top plot for $TE_{01}$ is obviously circularly symmetric and thus $m=0$ and the 1st  radial null is on the boundary with a single peak around the middle. There are better mode pictures than this, see, [for example](https://archive.org/details/waveguidehandboo0000marc/page/70/mode/2up). I leave the other for you to think about.