# Recognising magnetic wall and electric walls in circular waveguide mde

Tags: electromagnetism, waveguide

by definition magnetic wall is PMC where magnetic field perpendicular to the wall and electric field is parralel to the wall .PEC in the opposite.
In the top photo shown bellow taken from the link bellow the electric field is horizntal.
so there could be magnetc wall in parralel to the electric field.
In the buttom photo  we can put magnetic wall in perpandicular parralel to electric field.So why in the buttom photo they say that magnetic wall is not excited?

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329496727_Design_of_a_Ku-Band_High-Purity_Transducer_for_the_TM_01_Circular_Waveguide_Mode_by_Means_of_T-Type_Junctions/figures?lo=1

[image]

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761513/2451

Comment: what do $TE_{11s}$ and $TE_{11c}$ mean?

Comment: Hello hyportnex ,i am not sure  regarding the meaning.if you could please help me with an intuition to see magnetic wall or electric wall in the field.
So am i correct regarding the assumption that there is magnetic wall in both of the photos? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both plots the "dash dot" lines represent an even symmetry plane perpendicular to the  plane of the screen (paper). These show even symmetry because of the way the junction is excited with the two identical fields one coming form the left and the other from the right. Because of this even (electric field) symmetry relative to this plane the normal component of the E field and the tangential component of the H-field are zero, that is a PMC.

The "top left" corner circular waveguide is driven from the left and right symmetrically in two senses. Both are in phase and is also even symmetrical  in its own guide. This is because the "T" junction from which both come splits the fields of their rectangular waveguide input symmetrically and the mode in the rectangular mode itself is even symmetrical ($\text{TE}_{10}$ mode). Becasue of this double even symmetry the mode in the output circular guide has $2\times2$ four-fold even symmetry, therefore in the symmetry planes the electric field component normal to them must be zero, hence the PMC.

Comment: Hello hyportnex, so  if we take only the top photo where E-field lines are going from rught to left. so we can put PMC in horizontal  because E-field is parralel to it.
and we can put PEC to vertical becuse the e-fiel is vertical to it? Correct?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking, try to make a simple drawing...

Comment: Hello hyportnex,i Have made a drawing as you asked shown in the link bellow. as we can see electric field  going threw the green line so the green line is PEC.the E-field going parralel to the red line so the red line is PMC correct?

https://ibb.co/tCg0jBQ

Comment: To he extent I understand this, *both* red AND green lines represent PMC. The red is PMC because it is just the continuation of the field in the rectangular waveguide $TE_{10}$ that is even symmetrical $\text{cosine}$: zero at the walls, maximum in the middle. The green is PMC because it is the sum of two *identical* fields, one from the left and one from the right.